# Find distribution $Y=X^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

X~N(0,1). Find distribution $Y=X^2$

Can someone help me? I have no idea how to do it.
I could try to start like this:

$F_Y(t)=P(X^2<t)=P(-\sqrt(t)<X<\sqrt{t})$

Comment: I recall this is $\chi^2(1)$?

Comment: Consider two cases: $t \geqslant 0$ and $t < 0$, and use $P(a \leqslant X < b) = F_X(b) - F_X(a)$

Comment: probably $X^2(\omega)$ I have no info in this exercise

Comment: Recall that $N(0,1)$ is symmetric about $0$

Comment: "I could try to start like this" Good idea, and what comes next?

Comment: Thx @user159813! So $F_y(t)=P(X<\sqrt(t)=F_X(\sqrt(t)$

So next: $f_y(t)= \frac{d}{dt}F_x(\sqrt{t} = f_x(\sqrt{t} * \frac{1}{2* \sqrt{t}}$ and what next? Should I calculate $f(\sqrt{t})$ in normal distribution? It looks horrible ;/ and don't know how to compare with the original N

Comment: @PedroTamaroff [A First Course in Probability](http://www.amazon.com/First-Course-Probability-Sheldon-Ross/dp/0131856626) by Sheldon Ross is often mentioned in this context.

Comment: @keri I know that sounds bad but it actually really isn't that bad because, just try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off what you have, we have
$$P(-\sqrt{t}<X<\sqrt{t})=P(X<\sqrt{t})-P(X<-\sqrt{t})$$
but by symmetry we have 
$$P(<\sqrt{t})-\left(1-P(<\sqrt{t})\right)=2P(X<\sqrt{t})-1=2F(\sqrt(t))-1$$
Now to find distribution we will find pdf with what we have above thus we have 
$$f_{y}(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(F_{Y}(t)\right)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(2F_{X}(\sqrt{t})-1\right)=2\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}f_{X}(\sqrt{t})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}f_{X}(\sqrt{t})$$

Now from here just use pdf of $X$ (i.e. pdf of $N(0,1)$) and you should  get pdf for $Gamma(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ (i.e chi square with df =1). Recall also that $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: Thank you! I get it except of last sentence. Why you use Gamma distribution?

Comment: Oh you don't use it, just compare it to that Gamma Distributions pdf, they should be the same, and if they have same pdf they have same distribution

Comment: Ok, so next when I calculate I have got something like this:
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2t}*\pi}*exp^{\frac{-t}{2}}$ so the answer is $Y~N(\sqrt{t}$?

Comment: rewrite that as this $\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}}t^{\frac{1}{2}-1}e^{\frac{-1}{2}t}$ what is that pdf now (hint look at gamma)

Comment: True! Pdf is the same as gamma! So my answer is Y~Gamma(1/2,1/2)?
Wow! Nice. Thank you a lot!

Comment: yep which Gamma(n/2,1/2) is defined as chi square with df=n

Answer (score 0):

You are almost here, but you should consider two cases:
$$F_Y(t) = P(X^2 < t) = \begin{cases} 0,& t \leqslant 0\\ P(-\sqrt t < X < \sqrt t), & t > 0.\end{cases} = \\ \begin{cases} 0,& t \leqslant 0,\\ \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\sqrt t}^{\sqrt t}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx, & t > 0.\end{cases} = 
\begin{cases} 0,& t \leqslant 0,\\ \Phi(\sqrt t) - \Phi(- \sqrt t), & t > 0.\end{cases}$$
where $\Phi(t)$ is the cdf of standard normal distribution. The distribution of $Y$ is also known as $\chi^2(1)$, mentioned by Troy Woo. It is called [Chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with 1 degree of freedom.

*Updated:*
To find pdf instead of cdf you can use the formula:
$$f_{g(X)}(y) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n(y)}\Big|\frac{d}{dy}\big(g_k^{-1}(y)\big)\Big|f_X\big(g_k^{-1}(y)\big),$$
where $n(y)$ is the number of solutions to $y = g(x)$ and $g_k^{-1}(y)$ are these solutions.

From the above considerations it is clear that $f_{X^2}(y) = 0, \text{for }y \leqslant 0$. In case of $y = x^2$ the solutions are $g_1^{-1}(y) = -\sqrt y$ and $g_2^{-1}(y) = \sqrt y$. Applying the formula above we get:
$$ f_{X^2}(y) = \Big|\frac{d}{dy}\big(-\!\sqrt y\big)\Big|f_X\big(-\!\sqrt y\big) + \Big|\frac{d}{dy}\big(\sqrt y\big)\Big|f_X\big(\sqrt y\big) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-\frac{y}{2}},\ \text{for } y >0.$$

Comment: Ok, but

1)If I need to find a density function shouldn't be there $\frac{d}{dt}F_Y$ ?

Comment: keri: To find the PDF, the détour by the CDF is unnecessary, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables.

Comment: I am on basic probability course and don't know about chi-squared distribution and cdf. 
So the idea of the solution is integral of the distribution function and whats next?

Comment: keri: See the link provided by @Did, if you want to get density instead of cumulative distribution function.